# Using break to read first line of a list

Tags: python, list, break

Let's say I want to read and do something to only the first line in a file. I choose to say:

```
stuff = open('some_file.txt','rb')

for row in stuff:
    # do something to first line
    break
for row in stuff:
    # do something to all other lines
```

And this works as lone as I'm reading a file object and not something in memory.

Is there an argument against doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the first line with the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
firstline = next(stuff, '')  # default value '' if the file is empty

for row in stuff:
    # rest of the file
```

This works with any iterable. If you have a list of lines, you can do `lines[0]`, or first call [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) on the list.

Answer (score 0):

[fileinput](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) is a great module.

```
for line in fileinput.input(['some_file.txt']):
  if not fileinput.isfirstline():
    data = proces_line(line);
    output(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readline()` method:

```
stuff = open('some_file.txt','rb')

first = stuff.readline()

for row in stuff:
    # do something to all other lines
```

Comment: Only if you call `.readline()` *first*. A file used as an iterable uses a read buffer that interferes with `.readline()` calls, so you cannot mix the two in most cases.